# typedef struct isn't getting recognized in other header files

Tags: c, struct, typedef

I have multiple header files in my project. One of my header file is "Pwm.h". Inside this file I've declared a struct.

```
typedef struct PWM_T
{
    TIM_HandleTypeDef *pwmTimer;
    uint8_t channelNumber;
}Pwm_t;
```

In another header file, "Blower.h", I'm trying to use Pwm_t. And FYI, I've included "Pwm.h" in "Blower.h" with an include guard.

```
#ifndef SRC_PWM_H_
    #include "Pwm.h"
#endif
```

When I try to use Pwm_t in this file, I get an error

```
unknown type name 'Pwm_t'
```

If I go to the declaration of Pwm_t from "Blower.h", it takes me to the correct struct. Moreover, I've seen that if I redeclare Pwm_t in "Blower.h" it works. In other words, if I put the following line in "Blower.h", it works and there is no error.

```
typedef struct PWM_T Pwm_t;
```

So, it seems like "Blower.h" recognizes **struct PWM_T**, but doesn't recognize **Pwm_t**.

Some additional information for debugging:

There is another header file named "Fan.h" which is facing the same issue as "Blower.h" Weird thing is, if I redeclare **Pwm_t** in "Blower.h", the problem of recognizing Pwm_t in "Fan.h" goes away as well.

In my "main.h", I've included all the header files with include guard. And all the header file includes "main.h" with include guard.

Can someone explain why my typedef isn't working?

Comment: your include guard should be in the to-be-included header itself, not around the #include

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre].

Comment: Thanks @StefanRiedel. Fixing the include guards actually solved the issue. I was using it wrong. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I actually found the solution. The solution is to use include guards to prevent include cycle. I wasn't using include guards properly in my last example. The include guard should be in the .c file instead of

```
#ifndef SRC_PWM_H_
    #include "Pwm.h"
#endif
```